# State time evolution of a quantum harmonic oscillator with a Dirac-Delta function as an initial state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, dirac-delta-distributions

I have a question just like this Phys.SE problem [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129978/) with a difference that our system is a harmonic oscillator (rather than a free particle). A particle with mass $m$ is connected to a string with spring constant $k$ at $t=0$ with initial state function $\psi(x)=\delta(x-x_0)$. What is the state function at time $t$ and then calculate the $<x>_t$?

Comment: Your quantity is the Green's function $G(x,t;{x_0},0)$.

Comment: Thank you for comment, Do you have more detail or a reference?

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\psi (x,t) &=&<x|\exp [iH(t-t_{0})]\psi (t_{0})>=\int dy<x|\exp
[iH(t-t_{0})]|y>\psi (y,t_{0}) \\
&=&\int dyG(x,t;y,t_{0})\psi (y,t_{0})
\end{eqnarray*}
and in your case $\psi (y,t_{0})=\delta (y-x_{0})$. Here $H$ is the harmonic
oscillator Hamiltonian. For the Green's function I could not find an
expression on the web.