# Time evolution of Gaussian wave packet in free space with initial condition Dirac delta function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution, dirac-delta-distributions

I learn something about the Time evolution of Gaussian wave packet in free space.
if the  initial condition is a Dirac delta function at $t=0$, then the wave function is
$$
\psi (x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi it}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2it}}
$$

my question is it seems that the square of the modulus of

$$
\left |\psi (x,t)  \right |^{2}=\frac{1}{{2\pi t}}
$$

which has nothing to do with the independent variable x,
I can not understand the result.

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: here you can find answers to your question...
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/334574/362609

Comment: A free particle will *instantaneously* spread out equally over all space if its initial state is a delta function.